# In bash scripting the loop must continue until the specific keyword is typed

Tags: bash, loops

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "------------"
echo "Welcome Page"
echo "------------"
a="mango"
while true
do
echo "Type mango for exit"
read data
if [ $data -ne $a]; then
echo "Wrong choice"
exit 1
fi

done
```

The output is:

```
------------
Welcome Page
------------
Type mango for exit
mango
while.sh: line 10: [: missing `]'
Type mango for exit
```

Comment: paste your script at https://shellcheck.net for validation.

Comment: `if [ $data != $a ]; then`

Answer (score 2):

It's always good to put quotes around string variables to avoid spaces/newline conflicts.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "------------"
echo "Welcome Page"
echo "------------"
a="mango"
while true
do
    echo "Type mango for exit"
    read data
    echo $data
    if [ "$data" != "$a" ]; then
        echo "Wrong choice"
        exit 1
    fi
done
```

Comment: According to the required logic it should be `[ "$data" == "$a" ] && break || echo "Wrong, try again"`

Comment: i think program must exit but not break in case of loops.